# Check the status of updateRequest in ElasticSearch in Java

Tags: java, elasticsearch

Indexing using elastic search allows to check the status of the response:

```
import static org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentFactory.*;

IndexResponse response = client.prepareIndex("twitter", "tweet", "1")
        .setSource(jsonBuilder()
                    .startObject()
                        .field("user", "kimchy")
                        .field("postDate", new Date())
                        .field("message", "trying out Elasticsearch")
                    .endObject()
                  )
        .get();

// status has stored current instance statement.
RestStatus status = response.status();
```

When I need to upsert and using updateRequest instead of the response, is there an equivalent of a status method?

```
IndexRequest indexRequest = new IndexRequest("index", "type", "1")
        .source(jsonBuilder()
            .startObject()
                .field("name", "Joe Smith")
                .field("gender", "male")
            .endObject());
UpdateRequest updateRequest = new UpdateRequest("index", "type", "1")
        .doc(jsonBuilder()
            .startObject()
                .field("gender", "male")
            .endObject())
        .upsert(indexRequest);              
client.update(updateRequest).get();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to check for the number of successful, failed, or total operations.

For example, if the method to use is getTotal(),

rather than using get(), use actionGet() to get an UpdateResponse that contains the number of operations, including the total ones.

Putting them all together:

```
client.update(updateRequest).actionGet().getShardInfo().getTotal();
```

For others operations just change the getTotal() to the one you want.

The result is the number of operations in int.